# How to download only current date file from FTPS using pentaho

Tags: ftp, pentaho, etl, kettle, ftps

I have a remote server which contains many backup files in a directory. I have to download it everyday but only the files with the date modified is TODAY. How to do it using Pentaho?
Currently i used the job from pentaho **Get a File with FTPS**. But it will download all files. Idk how to filter for downloading only the files with today date modified.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can't apply a filter like that in "Get a file with SFTP" job entry.

However, a workaround might be to have the files stored in a variable folder or file name, according to the date they were modified.